# A question on topological group

Tags: topological-groups

Let $G$ be a topological group. We know that if $A$ is a closed subset of $G$ and $B$ a compact subset of $G$, then $A+B$ is a closed subset of $G$.
My question: Is the above statement true whenever $B$ is a $\sigma-$compact set of $G$?
Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You asked in your comment [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/448003/a-question-on-topological-group/448009#comment962190_448009) whether the claim is true if $B$ is additionally closed, i.e. you want a counterexample to:
$A$ is closed, $B$ is $\sigma$-compact and closed $\Rightarrow$ $A+B$ is closed.

Take, for example: $$A=B=\{(x,y)\in\mathbb R^2; y\ge1/|x|\}$$ in $(\mathbb R^2,+)$ (with the usual - coordinatewise - addition). Then $A+B=\{(x,y)\in\mathbb R^2; y>0\}$.

Answer (score 4):

Not in general: take $G=\Bbb R$, $A=\{0\}$, and $B=(0,1)$.

Comment: Let $B$ be closed. Is the statement true?

Comment: @aliakbar: Sorry: I apparently went to bed just before you asked that question. Fortunately, I see that Martin has answered it.

Answer (score 1):

No. Take $G$ to be the unit circle in the complex plane, $A=\{1\}$ and
$$B=\{e^{n\pi i\theta}\mid n\in\mathbb Z\}$$
where $\theta$ is an irrational number. $B$ is $\sigma$-compact because it is countable. $B$ is not closed, in fact it is dense.